# Unable to find a usable constructor for class Spring Enum Mybatis exception

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to setup ENUM TypeHandlers in spring mybatis, getting below exception,

> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Unable to find a usable
>   constructor for class
>   com.citi.aw.data.ibatis.KnownTypeHandlers$PortfolioTypeEnum

SqlConfig.xml

```
<configuration>
 <typeHandlers>
    <typeHandler javaType="com.citi.aw.entities.portfolio.PortfolioType" 
        handler="com.citi.aw.data.ibatis.KnownTypeHandlers$PortfolioTypeEnum"/></typeHandlers>
</configuration>
```

PortfolioType Enum

```
public enum PortfolioType
{
    PROPOSAL,
    INVESTABLE,
    MODEL,
    MODEL_STRATEGY,
    STRATEGY,
    CLIENT,
    FUND_OF_FUND,
    REFERENCE,
    MODEL_ALLOCATION    
}
```

---

```
Class KnownTypeHandlers
 public class KnownTypeHandlers 
    {
        public static abstract class PortfolioTypeEnum extends OrdinalEnumTypeHandler
        {
            public PortfolioTypeEnum()
            {
                super(PortfolioType.values());
            }
        }
}
```

---

```
Class OrdinalEnumTypeHandler

    public abstract class OrdinalEnumTypeHandler extends org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler<Object>
{
    private Object[] enumValues;

    protected OrdinalEnumTypeHandler(Object[] enumValues)
    {
        this.enumValues = enumValues;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException
    {
        int intValue = rs.getInt(columnName);
        return enumValues[intValue];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnPos) throws SQLException
    {
        int intValue = rs.getInt(columnPos);
        return enumValues[intValue];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResult(CallableStatement arg0, int arg1) throws SQLException
    {
        throw new SQLException("not implemented");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //@Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int pos, Object parameter, String jdbcType) throws SQLException
    {
        ps.setInt(pos, ((Enum)parameter).ordinal());
    }

    //@Override
    public Object valueOf(String stringValue)
    {
        return enumValues[Integer.parseInt(stringValue)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using MyBatis 3. So, You don't need to create any handler for the enum. MyBatis has one `typehandler` to Enum cases.

Se the [MyBatis 3 Configuration](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html) in the reference documentation:

> **typeHandlers**
>
> Whenever MyBatis sets a parameter on a PreparedStatement
>   or retrieves a value from a ResultSet, a TypeHandler is used to
>   retrieve the value in a means appropriate to the Java type. The
>   following table describes the default TypeHandlers.
>
> ...
>
> EnumTypeHandler -  Enumeration Type    - VARCHAR any string compatible type, as the code is stored (not index).

Then add to your configuration xml (In your case `SqlConfig.xml`:

```
<!-- mybatis-config.xml -->
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumTypeHandler"/>
</typeHandlers>
```